# Transformation of matrix with missing values for hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, clustering, matrix

Comparing different variables, I got a matrix with lots of missing values.

How do I have to transform the matrix below for hierarchical clustering?

[image]

What I have already tried:

```
x = read.csv("xyz.csv", sep = ";", row.names = 1, header = TRUE)
x[is.na(x)] = FALSE

# transform to correlation matrix
x = cor(t(x), method = "pearson")

# elbow method
fviz_nbclust(x, FUN = hcut, method = "wss")

# cluster with ward method
hc = hclust(dist(x), method = "ward.D2")

# show clusters
rect.hclust(hc,k=3, border="red")
plot(hc)
```

This clustering result looks wrong:

[image]

**dissimilarity matrix**

Right keyword for further search "dissimilarity matrix".
Now i tried to transform the matrix into a distance matrix.

```
x= as.dist(x, diag = TRUE)
hc = hclust(dist(x), method = "ward.D2")
plot(hc)
```

that´s not a solution yet

Comment: That isn't a solution. It's just hiding the error. The *meaning* of the result is likely completely messed up. Hacking random functions together without understanding what they do never was a good idea...

Comment: thanks for that hint. i will dive deeper into that cluster method.